# Rust adding .sort_by generates error: expected struct `Vec`, found `()`

Tags: sorting, vector, rust

Given the following code which compiles,

```
let alerts : Vec<Alert> = serde_json::from_value::<Vec<Alert>>(json) 
  .unwrap();
```

How come adding a `.sort_by_key` results in an error

> ```
> expected struct `Vec`, found `()`
> ```

Code that generated the error is,

```
let alerts : Vec<Alert> = serde_json::from_value::<Vec<Alert>>(json)
  .unwrap()
  .sort_by_key( |e| e.pub_millis );
```

Comment: [`sort_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_by_key) returns nothing ?

Comment: `sort_by_key` is not expected to be use in a chain function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for Vec:

```
pub fn sort_by_key<K, F>(&mut self, f: F) where
F: FnMut(&T) -> K,
K: Ord
```

This function doesn't have a return value, and will instead sort the slice in-place.  It therefore can't be used as a chained function, and must be given a mutable value.  If you'd like the alerts variable to be immutable, you can use the Temporary mutability idiom to make it mutable only long enough to sort it.  https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/idioms/temporary-mutability.html